# GLFWSetCursorPosCallback "cannot be resolved to type"

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm trying to setup mouse callbacks with LWJGL3. only problem is that all the tutorials and docs tell me to use the line `GLFWSetCursorPosCallback()` (with some parameters) but Eclipse keeps telling me that it cannot be resolved to a type, which i assume means it thinks it doesn't exist.

I have updated LWJGL to the latest nightly version, and every tutorial i look at says to use this line. Are they outdated? which is the correct line to use?

Example tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ownlj6W2Lss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the lower case function:

```
GLFWCursorPosCallback cursorPosCallback = new GLFWCursorPosCallback() {
    @Override
    public void invoke(long window, double xpos, double ypos) {
        // ...
    }
};
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(windowId, cursorPosCallback);
```

You can either statically import it:

```
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSetCursorPosCallback;
```

or access it directly through its class:

```
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;

GLFW.glfwSetCursorPosCallback(/*...*/);
```

Comment: The method glfwSetCursorPosCallback(long, GLFWCursorPosCallback) is undefined for the type Main